# How to display imageview in scrollview to all screen

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I'm trying to show picture to all screen, when it isn't in scrollView all works ok, but when I put imageview to scrollview they displayed to 60-80% of screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Background">



    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView7">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/asana_image"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@color/Transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/noimage"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="false" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:id="@+id/videoplay_but"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_corn_bg"
                    android:src="@drawable/video"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:padding="18dp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:id="@+id/sound_but"
                    android:src="@drawable/sound_image"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_corn_bg"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/videoplay_but"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/videoplay_but"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/videoplay_but"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:padding="18dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView55"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView56" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView57"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView55"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/VideoLay"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <VideoView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/videoAsana"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

and in Fragment:

```
if(imgFile.exists()){

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

            asana_image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);


        }
```

Where is my mistake?
Thanks!!!

ScreenShots:
[image: When no image]
[image: When image exist]

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that your relative layout is inside the scrollview so you should not give the attribute `android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView7"` to your relative layout.

Next is that you should give `match_parent` to your scrollview instead of `wrap_content`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Background">



    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView7">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/asana_image"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@color/Transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/noimage"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="false" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:id="@+id/videoplay_but"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_corn_bg"
                    android:src="@drawable/video"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:padding="18dp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:id="@+id/sound_but"
                    android:src="@drawable/sound_image"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_corn_bg"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/videoplay_but"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/videoplay_but"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/videoplay_but"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:padding="18dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relative1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView55"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView56" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView57"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView55"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/VideoLay"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <VideoView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/videoAsana"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add android:layout_above="@+id/VideoLay" to your scrollview

Comment: with this I can see only VideoLay.

Comment: before  asana_image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap); all good, and after scroll isn't working.(

Comment: can  you attach a screenshot